# Adobe Analytics Implementation

Tags: javascript, adobe, implementation, tagging

When user hits on renewal 06/24 link we are getting Activity map as pagename: current-policy, link:RENEWAL 06/24, region: stand-tab, I want to change link name to renewal which I did. but pagename is changed to policy-renewal, I don't want it to be changed how to fix it.

What did I do wrong?

```
if (dataLayer.screenId == "policy-view"){
   var x = document.querySelector("#renewal-tab");
     x.addEventListener("click", () => {
     s.forceLink = "Renewal";
     s.forceRegion = "stand-tab";
    });
 }
```

This is the code I have tried

getting output as
page:policy-renewal,
link:Renewal,
region:stand-tab

Expected
page:current-policy,
link:Renewal,
region:stand-tab